# Error on "close" click

Tags: bug, status-norepro

When I click close in [mysql---which type i should use?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4637965/mysql-which-type-i-should-use) this is what I get in console:

> uncaught exception: [Exception... "Component returned failure code: 0x805e000a [nsIXMLHttpRequest.open]" nsresult: "0x805e000a ()" location: "JS frame :: http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js :: anonymous :: line 127" data: no]

Firefox 3.6.13

In chrome everything is good.

It worked fine just few days ago, before an update when new throbbers with squares instead of round one came.

**UPD**: it was caused by AdBlock+ :-S So I need to whitelist SO and watch its commercials now, weird.

Comment: What's a "throble"?

Comment: @Chris Lively: throbbler (typo in the question). It is a some animated gif drawn when you're waiting until ajax is completed. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Throbber#Spinning_wheel

Comment: Interesting read.  I never knew there was a name for that.  Thanks :)

Comment: @Chris Lively: oh, its actual name is **throbber**, without `l`. Don't even know why I always though it is throbbLer :-S

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have 3.6.13 and I was able to successfully click close.  Sounds like it might have been a transient error?

Comment: It is not transient for me - it reproduces each time.